# How to write DSL for data tables, similar to Spock?

Tags: groovy

I have seen spock, which accepts this syntax ( what is called Data tables):

```
    a | b | c
    1 | 3 | 3
    7 | 4 | 4
    0 | 0 | 0
```

Lets say this in data_table.groovy, how one can write the DSL so that the above is transformed into xml for each row:

```
<a>1</a>
<b>3</b>
<c>3</c>
... other rows
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the input exactly? A data table as a string or a single row?

Comment: only the first row?  what have you tried so far?  is `3>` a typo?

Comment: No it will be in groovy itself, I want to write the DSL parser for it. So that user can write something like this and the parser will convert into xml.

Comment: this hardly qualifies as a DSL.  this just is formatted data.  do you need some formulas there or why must this be a groovy file?

Comment: The reason being is, why it needs to be in groovy file is that, end user will directly write them in groovy file. I doesnt want them to write in string's. Rather direct code in groovy!

Comment: then you should add all this information to the question and provide a real world example of the things, you want to have/do with the DSL, otherwise just doing eachLine/split would be enough.

Comment: Any idea of how I can do the same with DSL groovy?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GroovyTables](https://github.com/tools4j/groovy-tables) (disclaimer: I am the author of GroovyTables)

1. Create a method which takes a closure argument, uses GroovyTables to construct a list-of-arrays, and then loop through the table to create the XML:

   ```
   private String toXml(Closure closure) {
       List<Object[]> rows = GroovyTables.createListOfArrays(closure)
       Iterator<Object[]> rowsIterator = rows.iterator()
       Object[] headingRow = rowsIterator.next()
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
       while (rowsIterator.hasNext()) {
           Object[] row = rowsIterator.next()
           sb.append("<row>\n")
           for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
               sb.append("    <${headingRow[i].name}>${row[i]}</${headingRow[i].name}>\n")
           }
           sb.append("</row>\n")
       }
       return sb.toString()
   }
   ```
2. And then use your new method:

   ```
   def xml = toXml {
       a | b | c
       1 | 3 | 3
       7 | 4 | 4
       0 | 0 | 0
   }
   println xml
   ```

   Will produce:

   ```
   <row>
       <a>1</a>
       <b>3</b>
       <c>3</c>
   </row>
   <row>
       <a>7</a>
       <b>4</b>
       <c>4</c>
   </row>
   <row>
       <a>0</a>
       <b>0</b>
       <c>0</c>
   </row>
   ```